# What cause the process bar error in Conda environment?

Tags: python, console, conda, progress

After activating conda environment (with python 3.8), all commands with progress bar will be broken
[image]

Some commands with long progress bar, it breaks to multi lines at every second like this
[image]

To my observe, I figure out that the latest status does not display at the bottom of the screen but always display toward the top and overlay on the text of previous commands
[image]

Moreover, some Unicode characters not display correctly when print out
[image]

These problems do not appear when I deactivate the environment and run the same command in base environment.

Can someone help me to figure out what the problem is and how to fix that?
Thank you.

Comment: `tqdm` is the library that does progress bars. Looks like it was installed as a dependency of `gdown` for you. So I would think your culprit is `gdown`.

Comment: @gallen gdown is not the problem. I just add more example about the problem. All these command work correctly in the base environment and event in native bash shell without conda.

Comment: Well, the progress bars being printed are definitely `tqdm` bars. [TQDM on Windows](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/454) has issues with non-ascii characters, as discussed in that thread. It's older, but maybe still useful? Unless you add examples of your code that generates these progress bars, it's difficult to help you.

Comment: @gallen it's putty client connect to the remote Ubuntu server. As I mentioned in the question, it's not only a problem with tqdm, it's an issue of all command with progress bar, like 'pip install'. All these problem will not appear when I deactivate the custom environment and run these command in the base environment